# how to get POST data as text in servant

Tags: haskell, servant

I want to get raw POST request data in a servant and then parse it by myself:

Servant code:

```
type API = "reg" 
               :> ReqBody '[PlainText] Text
               :> Post '[PlainText] String
      


server :: Env -> Server API
server env = reg 

  where
    reg d  = do 
               **-- HERE I WANT TO PARSE d MYSELF**
               liftIO $ print "reg!"
               return "reg"
```

Then I try access with:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain;charset-utf8" -data "email=1&name=2&pwd=3" http://localhost:8080/reg
```

I got

```
curl: (3) URL rejected: Bad hostname
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 11 Feb 2024 11:12:42 GMT
Server: Warp/3.3.31
```

How to make this work?

I expect the successfull request

Comment: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type#syntax

Comment: `-data` => `--data` or `-d`

Comment: I try to fix booth to "text/html;" and -d, but result same..

Comment: It seem "charset-utf8" must be replaced with "charset=utf-8" :) and it's work

Comment: @danidiaz you can post answer